# How to read stdout from python subprocess popen non-blockingly on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am suffering from the Windows Python subprocess module.
This is test code1(named test1.py):

```
import subprocess as sbp


with sbp.Popen('python tests/test2.py',stdout=sbp.PIPE) as proc:
    print('parent process')
    print(proc.stdout.read(1))
    print('end.')
```

and test code2(named `test2.py`):

```
import random
import time

def r():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(0, 100)


for i in  r():
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Generally, the test code2 generates random integer(0~100) and print it out infinitely.
I want the test code1 create a subprocess and launch it, read the stdout in realtime(not waiting for subprocess finished).
But when I run the code, the output is :

```
python.exe test1.py
parent process
```

It blocks on stdout.read() forever.
I have tried:

1. Replace `stdout.read` with communicate(), doesn't work as [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) expected, it will blocking until subprocess terminate.
2. use poll() methods to detect subprocess and read n bytes, forever block on read()
3. Modify the test2.code, only generate one nunber and break the loop. The father process print it out immediately(I think it's because child process terminated)

I searched a lot of similiar answers and did as they suggested(use stdout instead of communicate), but still didn't work?

*Could anyone help me explaining why and how to do it?*

This is my platform information:
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Any reason why it needs to be `Popen` specifically? Why not use `subprocess.check_output`? Or does `check_output` not do realtime reading?

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri Yeah, `check_output` is similiar to `run`, it return until subprocess terminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with Python's output buffering (for a child process in your case). Try disabling the buffering and your code should work. You can do it by either running python with `-u` key, or calling `sys.stdout.flush()`.

To use the `-u` key you need to modify the argument in the call to `Popen`, to use the `flush()` call you need to modify the `test2.py`.

Also, your `test1.py` would print just a single number, because you read only 1 byte from the pipe, instead of reading them in a loop.

Solution 1:

test1.py

```
import subprocess as sbp

with sbp.Popen(["python3", "-u", "./test2.py"], stdout=sbp.PIPE) as proc:
    print("parent process")
    while proc.poll() is None:  # Check the the child process is still running
        data = proc.stdout.read(1)  # Note: it reads as binary, not text
        print(data)
    print("end")
```

This way you don't have to touch the `test2.py` at all.

Solution 2:

test1.py

```
import subprocess as sbp

with sbp.Popen("./test2.py", stdout=sbp.PIPE) as proc:
    print("parent process")
    while proc.poll() is None:  # Check the the child process is still running
        data = proc.stdout.read(1)  # Note: it reads as binary, not text
        print(data)
    print("end")
```

test2.py

```
import random
import time
import sys

def r():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(0, 100)

for i in  r():
    print(i)
    sys.stdout.flush()  # Here you force Python to instantly flush the buffer
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will print each received byte on a new line, e.g.:

```
parent process
b'9'
b'5'
b'\n'
b'2'
b'6'
b'\n'
```

You can switch the pipe to text mode by providing `encoding` in arguments or providing `universal_newlines=True`, which will make it use the default encoding. And then write directly to `sys.stdout` of your parent process. This will basically  stream the output of a child process to the output of the parent process.

test1.py

```
import subprocess as sbp
import sys

with sbp.Popen("./test2.py", stdout=sbp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
    print("parent process")
    while proc.poll() is None:  # Check the the child process is still running
        data = proc.stdout.read(1)  # Note: it reads as binary, not text
        sys.stdout.write(data)
    print("end")
```

This will provide the output as if the `test2.py` is executed directly:

```
parent process
33
94
27
```

Comment: You point out the key -- the child process output buffered!   
Thank you Nikita, both of the 2 solutions are great. This is a test code for situition to transmit data(large data) between child and parent process. So byte format is ok, and also your example of using poll() in a loop works for me. Thank you again!